# Pycharm: Error while parsing "docker-compose.yml": Process `docker-compose config` failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm

This error appears randomly when I'm working with docker-compose on Windows 10, sometimes after pycharm already working with docker-compose as interpreter. 
I tried:

- Make sure docker-compose file is valid, without tabs instead of spaces.
- Use yml and yaml suffixes (sometimes yaml works and yml doesn't, sometimes both are working or not working)
- Add project-compose to configuration files.

Problem is 'solved' just after rebooting, and then happened again.

Answer (score 9):

## Linux here

tl;dr: same solution as for windows

1. check path to docker-compose executable:

   ```
   ➤ which docker-compose
   /home/voy/.pyenv/shims/docker-compose
   ```
2. Go to `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Docker | Tools | Docker Compose Executable` and paste docker compose executable path from above

   [image: linux is better]
3. Restart pycharm

Answer (score 3):

Here is a JetBrains issue about this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-49652

And another post:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000129510-Couldn-t-refresh-skeletons-for-remote-interpreter-Docker

1. They suggest multiple things, first I had to change the docker-compose executable path, as PyCharm found the docker-compose.txt first, I needed to set it to docker-compose.exe.
   [image]

2. After this the problem still occured from time to time, but restarting PyCharm fixed it. Though it takes for a few minutes to index everything and reload the project.
3. Line endings can also be an issue, if in the docker-compose.yml set to use CRLF instead of LF, that can be a cause to fail parsing as well. I suggest to use a .editorconfig file to control your line endings, that seemed to help as well. Also setting your git autocrlf to 'input' might help if you use Windows.
4. Slowest one is posted on the forum:

- remove pycharm helper containers: `$ docker rm -f $(docker ps -a | grep pycharm_helper | awk '{print $1}')`
- invalidate caches and restart PyCharm

No a great solutions yet as I know, unfortunately.

Comment: broke for me after updating docker-desktop. Removing the pycharm helper container did it for me

Answer (score 0):

This issue started to appear after updating Docker Desktop, and pruning PyCharm-related volumes. The described solutions here and in other threads did not help. The only solution that worked for me was updating PyCharm itself.